# JQuery function present but saying method undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, methods

I am relatively new to Jquery and so accept that the answer could be pretty obvious. I have a plugin that provides a function, but when I run my program I get the console error:

```
Cannot call method 'createEvent' of undefined
```

Like I said I have probably missed something simple but I cannot find what. The var desiredValue is, of course, retrieving the correct data and I have ensured the plugin is linked correctly in the header. If anyones got any advice they can give that would be very much appreciated! Thanks.

```
function createEvent(title,location,notes, startDate, endDate){
  var title= "My Appt";
  var location = "Los Felix";
  var notes = "me testing";
  var startDate = "2012-11-23 09:30:00";
  var endDate = "2012-11-23 12:30:00";

  cal.createEvent(title,location,notes,startDate,endDate);
}

var cal;

$(document).ready(function() {
  cal = window.plugins.calendarPlugin;


  $('.calinfo').live('click', function() {    
    var desiredValue = $(this).parent().prev().find('.calendar').val();                                                
    var calInfo = desiredValue.split(',');

    createEvent(calInfo[0], calInfo[1], calInfo[2], calInfo[3], calInfo[4]);
  });                              
});
```

Comment: Is window.plugins.calendarPlugin defined?

Comment: Can you console.log(window.plugins.calendarPlugin) ? Also this plugin has two required frameworks, did you include those?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy ah your familiar with the plugin? Yes ive included the 2 frameworks

Answer (score 1):

Place a debug point after the cal assignment. The problem is this line of code within your function:

```
cal.createEvent(title,location,notes,startDate,endDate);
```

cal is undefined in that context and scope.

I have a feeling that

```
cal = window.plugins.calendarPlugin;
```

is not assigned correctly.

... thanks for the link (see comments) -- @Ohgodwhy.

That plugin isn't written very well, honestly. But, what you should do is just edit the first line of your function:

```
window.plugins.calendarPlugin.prototype.createEvent = function(title,location,notes, startDate, endDate){
```

Whenever you call the function just use cal.createEvent (you'll need to edit the click event handler as such.

This is going to sound stupid but... are you sure the plugin JS file was included and executed before this script? If you're including the plugin (calendar plugin javascript file) after this script executes, the calendarPlugin object won't exist (hence, it will remain undefined)!

Comment: have a look here -> https://github.com/felixactv8/Phonegap-Calendar-Plugin-ios that's the proper method to invoke his action

Comment: Regardless, there is nothing in your code which assigns your function as a property of cal.

Comment: Also, you can place the var cal inside the dom-ready function (just use var cal = win... (first line inside dom-ready function). And, of course, remove the current var cal; declaration.

Comment: @say2joe Thanks! but I've had no luck...still nothing occurs

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Sorry, just got your comment. My response (in regard to your's toward me) was not directed at you -- but, instead, at the author of the question. I submitted my comment before even seeing your's appear.

Comment: @MeltingDog ... I hate to say this, but, I think this question may be deserving of a live example (something I can debug in a browser). If that's possible, please let me know. Could probably solve your issue within 2-5 minutes with a live debugging tool on my end. There is simply not enough code herein (if my suggestion or others did not work) to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

It is a scope issue which is preventing the `var cal` from being hoisted to the top. Move your function declaration within the ready function. You're also getting undefined because you're calling `createEvent` as a method of `cal` but you haven't created a class object.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cal;
    cal = window.plugins.calendarPlugin;

    $('.calinfo').live('click', function() {
        var desiredValue = $(this).parent().prev().find('.calendar').val();
        var calInfo = desiredValue.split(',');

        createEvent(calInfo[0], calInfo[1], calInfo[2], calInfo[3], calInfo[4]);
    });

    function createEvent(title, location, notes, startDate, endDate) {
        var title = "My Appt";
        var location = "Los Felix";
        var notes = "me testing";
        var startDate = "2012-11-23 09:30:00";
        var endDate = "2012-11-23 12:30:00";

        cal.createEvent(title, location, notes, startDate, endDate);
    }

});​
```

Comment: In his original posting, cal was declared globally. It is not good practice, in the least, but not the source of his problem.