# PhoneGap/Cordova Plugin - how to set up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

Ive installed the Calendar plugin for iOS successfully (I think) from here:
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/CalendarPlugin

However I just cant seem to get it working.
So far heres what I have done:

1. Dropped the calendar .h and .m files into the plugins folder of my
   project.
2. Added the calendar.js file to my directory structure and linked in
   the header
3. Added the EventKit and EventKitUI frameworks to my project
4. Added the term calendarPlugin to my cordova.plist file

And 5. Added the code below to the page one which I want to save:

```
window.plugins.calendarPlugin.prototype.createEvent = function(title,location,notes, startDate, endDate){
                var title= "My Appt";
                var location = "Los Felix";
                var notes = "me testing";
                var startDate = "2012-11-23 09:30:00";
                var endDate = "2012-11-23 12:30:00";



   cal.createEvent(title,location,notes,startDate,endDate);
            }

            $(document).ready(function() {
                    cal = window.plugins.calendarPlugin;
                    var cal;

 $('.calinfo').live('click', function() {

          var desiredValue = $(this).parent().prev().find('.calendar').val();
                                             console.log(desiredValue);                                               
                                             var calInfo = desiredValue.split(',');

             createEvent(calInfo[0], calInfo[1], calInfo[2], calInfo[3], calInfo[4]);

                                            });                              
                    });
```

When I run it noting happens. Have I missed something?

Comment: Did you just ask this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11876074/jquery-function-present-but-saying-method-undefined

Comment: Did you add it to your cordova.plist file, under plugins?

Comment: @ahren yes - I thought I should be more specific. It seems to be a PhoneGap question as well as a JavaScript question

Comment: @Jeemusu oops missed that step above - yes I did

Comment: @MeltingDog - I suggest you edit your original question then, instead of posting another...

Comment: have u read a readme file from Git Project's folder?

Comment: @AamirKhan yes and followed it exactly

Comment: @ahren Thanks but I feel that this is a different question. If you can see I have incorporated what I have learnt from the previous question into this one. The first question was about the JavaScript error that I was recieving. That has been resolved but as I am still getting and error I believe it has something to do with the way I have set up in PhoneGap. This question is meant to prompt the kind of suggestions Aamir and Jeemmusu have presented. The JavaScript is there so people dont have to ask 'have you tried this in JavaScript'...etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont't use $(document).ready(function());. Rather use device ready. Call the function onBodyLoad() on body load.

```
    function onBodyLoad()
        {        
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
            deviceready = true;
        }
```

//////////////////////////////////

```
    function onDeviceReady()
    {
       // Your code goes here

    }
```

Comment: Thanks - but no luck on my end :(